# Как при нажатии на итем листбокста передать этот итем со всеми свойствами в код?

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, windows-phone-7

Есть кастомный листбокс, интерфейс каждого итема выбирается селектором, в зависмости от наличия некоторых свойств. Один из интерфейсов имеет 2 текстбокса и имейдж.  Мне нужно при нажатии на имейдж, перейти на другую страницу и открыть в ней браузер с урл, которая является свойством итема, на который нажали. С передачей инфы на другую страницу проблем нет, но вот как достать урл именно того итема на который нажали? По индексу я могу добраться до любого итема коллекции, но мне же не известно какой именно итем имеет имейдж и урл.

ps: сендер события нажатия имеет тип image, строка типа

```
New tmp = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as New);
```

не срабатывает.

Comment: Сделай правильную генерацию событий по клику на Image.

Comment: можно поподробней? в xaml у меня стоит <Image Source="{Binding Video[0].Big}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Tap="Video_Tap"  /> а в коде -         private void Video_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            New tmp = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as New); и тд.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на вопрос 
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779828/how-to-get-the-listbox-items-properties-after-event-tap)